# Wordpress - Converting static page to simple one page theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I need to convert simple one page web to the Wordpress side.

All I need to do is be able to change texts, not layout.

Page has a sections. How should I develop the page, to make each section text editable.

As far as I understand, in wordpress menu I will create several pages, which will represent each section in my page.

but how can I do that ? Thank you so much!